# Concatenate using 'FOR' loop in VALUE operator with 'BASE' addition?

Tags: abap, internal-tables

Is it possible to mix in a `FOR` with `CONCATENATE` along with `BASE` statement?

Normally, `itab1 = VALUE #( BASE itab1 ( value1 ) )` will append `line1` into `itab1` without overwriting. Shouldn't it be the same when using `FOR` along with `BASE`?

This is my thought process, but I get the `No component exists with the name "FOR"` error:

```
itab1 = 
VALUE #( 
   BASE itab1
   ( value1 && value2 )
   ( VALUE #( 
       FOR line in itab2
       ( line-fld1 && line-fld2 ) )
   ).
```

Comment: You may append the lines of an internal table only by using `( LINES OF itab )`, so in your case it should be `( LINES OF VALUE #( ... ) )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried out what Sandra had suggested in the comments and it worked like a charm:

> You may append the lines of an internal table only by using ( LINES OF
> itab ), so in your case it should be ( LINES OF VALUE #( ... ) ) –
> Sandra Rossi

```
itab1 = 
VALUE #( BASE itab1 ( value1 && value2 )
       ( LINES OF VALUE #( FOR line in itab2 ( line-fld1 && line-fld2 ) ) ).
```

Answer (score 1):

> Shouldn't it be the same when using FOR along with BASE

Yes, the semantics is the same. You use `BASE` for preserving the rows of the [LHS](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_755_index_htm/7.55/en-US/abenequals_operator.htm) when adding rows of [RHS](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_755_index_htm/7.55/en-US/abenequals_operator.htm), and [line specification](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_755_index_htm/7.55/en-US/abenvalue_constructor_params_lspc.htm#!ABAP_ALTERNATIVE_1@1@) is the same:

```
itab1 = VALUE #( BASE itab1 FOR line in itab2 ( matnr = line-matnr
                                                maktx = line-matnr && line-spras
                                                spras = line-spras ) ).
```

However, there is a nuance you should remember here: you cannot put the same itab to the *inline-declared* LHS, to the `BASE` source and to the FOR loop, it will give you infinite loop and **TSV_TNEW_PAGE_ALLOC_FAILED** dump.